# Use CSS3 transitions on the opacity property for tabbed content does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple tabbed content box in HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery.

It works fine *except* I have not been able to fade the content in gradually, using CSS *transitions* and *opacity*. Here is the code:

```js
$("#filters_switch").on("click", "li", function() {
    $('#filters_switch li').removeClass('tab_selected');
    $(this).addClass('tab_selected');
    $('#filters_content > div').removeClass('tab_selected');
    $('#' + $(this).find('a').data('href')).addClass('tab_selected');
});
```

```css
#filters_switch {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
}
#filters_switch li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#filters_switch li.tab_selected a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#filters_switch a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #962b27;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
#filters_content .tab {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
#filters_content .tab.tab_selected {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#filters_content .tab h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters_switch" class="tabnav clearfix">
  <li id="filters_standard_link" class="tabnav_li tab_selected">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_standard">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="filters_advanced_link" class="tabnav_li">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_advanced">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="filters_content" class="tabs">
    <div id="filters_standard" data-id="filters_standard" class="tab tab_selected">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="filters_advanced" data-id="filters_advanced" class="tab">
      <h2>Esse odit sapiente odio deleniti</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since transitions can't be used on the `display` property, I have used it on the `opacity`, expecting the content to be firstly displayed, but with *0 opacity*, then with opacity **slowly** brought to 1.

Yet, this does not happen. Why? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition doesn't get applied to certain properties including display property so you can use a workaround using, z-index, and position absolute, like the example..

```js
$("#filters_switch").on("click", "li", function() {
    $('#filters_switch li').removeClass('tab_selected');
    $(this).addClass('tab_selected');
    $('#filters_content > div').removeClass('tab_selected');
    $('#' + $(this).find('a').data('href')).addClass('tab_selected');
});
```

```css
#filters_switch {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
}
#filters_switch li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#filters_switch li.tab_selected a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#filters_switch a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #962b27;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
#filters_content {
  position:relative;
}
#filters_content .tab {
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#filters_content .tab.tab_selected {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

#filters_content .tab h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight" bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters_switch" class="tabnav clearfix">
  <li id="filters_standard_link" class="tabnav_li tab_selected">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_standard">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="filters_advanced_link" class="tabnav_li">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_advanced">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="filters_content" class="tabs">
    <div id="filters_standard" data-id="filters_standard" class="tab tab_selected">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="filters_advanced" data-id="filters_advanced" class="tab">
      <h2>Esse odit sapiente odio deleniti</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are partially right: the `display` property does not support transitions, but, `opacity` *usually* does. What puzzles me is that in this case, it does *not*.

Comment: It doesn't because you are using opacity with the display property..., so the display property will block the transition animation...

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can't apply CSS transitions to `display`, so instead, try using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` while absolutely positioning the tabs.

HIH

```js
$("#filters_switch").on("click", "li", function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass('tab_selected')){
   $(this).addClass('tab_selected').siblings('li').removeClass('tab_selected');
    
    $('#' + $(this).find('a').data('href')).fadeIn('slow').siblings('div.tab').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

```css
#filters_switch {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
}
#filters_switch li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#filters_switch li.tab_selected a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#filters_switch a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #962b27;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
#filters_content .tab {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: none;
 
  position: absolute;
}
#filters_content .tab.tab_selected {
  display: block;
  //opacity: 1;
}

#filters_content .tab h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight" bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters_switch" class="tabnav clearfix">
  <li id="filters_standard_link" class="tabnav_li tab_selected">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_standard">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="filters_advanced_link" class="tabnav_li">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_advanced">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="filters_content" class="tabs">
    <div id="filters_standard" data-id="filters_standard" class="tab tab_selected">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="filters_advanced" data-id="filters_advanced" class="tab">
      <h2>Esse odit sapiente odio deleniti</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dol odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to apply a transition to the `opacity`, not the `display` property.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir; well, for what is worth, that's exactly what `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` do, change the `opacity` in a transition and apply display block/none at the end

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify `jQuery` and `css`. with the use of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, you can achieve what you want

```js
$("#filters_switch").on("click", "li", function() {
    var toggleSection = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
    $('.tabnav li').removeClass('tab_selected');
    $(this).addClass('tab_selected');
    $('#filters_content > div').fadeOut(250); 
    $("[data-tab="+toggleSection+"]").delay(300).fadeIn(250);
});
```

```css
#filters_switch {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
}
#filters_switch li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#filters_switch li.tab_selected a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
#filters_switch a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #962b27;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
#filters_content .tab {
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* display: none; */
  /* opacity: 0; */
  /* -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s; */
}
#filters_content .tab.tab_selected {
  display: block;
  /* opacity: 1; */
}

#filters_content .tab h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#filters_content > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters_switch" class="tabnav clearfix">
  <li id="filters_standard_link" class="tabnav_li tab_selected" data-toggle="section-one">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_standard">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="filters_advanced_link" class="tabnav_li" data-toggle="section-two">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_advanced">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="filters_content" class="tabs">
    <div id="filters_standard" data-id="filters_standard" data-tab="section-one" class="tab tab_selected">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="filters_advanced" data-id="filters_advanced" class="tab" data-tab="section-two">
      <h2>Esse odit sapiente odio deleniti</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/87qkLh15/3/)

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the 
answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed `display:none` from `.tab` and positioned them absolute.

```js
$("#filters_switch").on("click", "li", function() {
  $('#filters_switch li').removeClass('tab_selected');
  $(this).addClass('tab_selected');
  $('#filters_content > div').removeClass('tab_selected');
  $('#' + $(this).find('a').data('href')).addClass('tab_selected');
});
```

```css
#filters_switch {
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  text-align: center;
}

#filters_switch li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#filters_switch li.tab_selected a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#filters_switch a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #962b27;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

#filters_content {
  position: relative;
}

#filters_content .tab {
  padding: 0 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}

#filters_content .tab.tab_selected {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#filters_content .tab h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight" bold;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters_switch" class="tabnav clearfix">
  <li id="filters_standard_link" class="tabnav_li tab_selected">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_standard">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="filters_advanced_link" class="tabnav_li">
    <a class="tabnavlink" href="#" data-href="filters_advanced">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="filters_content" class="tabs">
  <div id="filters_standard" data-id="filters_standard" class="tab tab_selected">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="filters_advanced" data-id="filters_advanced" class="tab">
    <h2>Esse odit sapiente odio deleniti</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse odit sapiente, odio deleniti asperiores iusto animi hic sint voluptate incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```